# Extracting table heading then adding to array list for all records held within the table

Tags: java, html, for-loop, jsoup

I am currently scraping the scores from the following site: http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/rugby-union/results and storing these within four array lists.

Here is my code for getting the table contents:

```
for (Element table : doc.select("table:first-of-type")) { 
                         for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                              Elements td = row.select("td"); 
                              List1.add(td.get(0).text());
                              List2.add(td.get(1).text());
                              List3.add(td.get(2).text());
                              List4.add(td.get(3).text());
                         }
                    }
```

I would get the output of:

```
List 1: [Worcester, Sale, Ulster]
List 2: [22 - 23, 24 - 19, 10 - 7]
List 3: [Leicester, Gloucester, Ospreys]
List 4: [Full Time, Full Time, Full Time]
```

But as the scores are all displayed together with scores from different tournaments. I now want to parse the Tournament name contained within `<p class="table-description">Aviva Premiership</p>` - 
For example there will be two results for the Aviva Premiership then one for Rabodirect Pro12. So for the first two results, Aviva Premiership would be added to an array list then for the next result Rabodirect Pro12 would be added.

Here is my current attempt:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup
                  .connect("http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/rugby-union/results") 
                  .timeout(5000)
                  .get();

      for (Element pTag : doc.select("p[class=table-description]")) {
           List1.add(pTag.text());

           for (Element row : doc.select("tr")) {
                     Elements td = row.select("td"); 

                     List2.add(td.get(0).text());
                     List3.add(td.get(1).text());
                     List4.add(td.get(2).text());
                     List5.add(td.get(3).text());
                }
```

But this will only parse each one and I can't seem to work out how to add it to each result before moving onto the next tournament name.

The desired output would look this this from my current example:

```
List 5: [Aviva Premiership, Aviva Premiership, RaboDirect Pro12]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `div.table-table-stats` elements as a starting point and iterate over them. Inside the loop you can use the table as starting point to get the league name and then the tr elements. In order to repeat the league info for each game at the correct list index, you need to put the `list1.add(dataTable.select("p.table-description").text());` inside the inner loop.

If you want to to include the day of the game you can use a similar approach one level up.

```
Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/rugby-union/results") 
            .timeout(5000)
            .get();

List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(); //league name
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list4 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list5 = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Element dataTable : doc.select("div.table-table-stats")) {

    for (Element row : dataTable.select("tr")) {
           Elements td = row.select("td"); 
           list1.add(dataTable.select("p.table-description").text());
           list2.add(td.get(0).text());
           list3.add(td.get(1).text());
           list4.add(td.get(2).text());
           list5.add(td.get(3).text());
    }
}
System.out.println(list1);
System.out.println(list2);
System.out.println(list3);
System.out.println(list4);
System.out.println(list5);
```

PS: You should consider filling a helper object with the data of a game. Using several lists seems like a poor design choice.